# Custom Kafka Source on Apache Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, etl, apache-flink

I have a project where I need to subscribe to specific topics related to tasks registered in a database. Each task is related to a topic and can do a specific transformation described from task metadata. The tasks can be registered, updated or disabled by another system and the flink job must reflect those change without need to restart the job.

Based on that I tried something similar to https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/03/24/demo-fraud-detection-2.html where I have two source functions, one fetching the database for tasks in a interval manner and the other subscribed to topics using a pattern and a custom deserializer (to get topic name).

Then a CoProcessFunction is responsible for join the data from the Task Source and Kafka Source keeping a list of tasks related to each topic (the list is refreshed every time the Task Source fetch data from database). After that the transformations are applied and transformed data saved on the specific systems.

[image]

My problem with this design is that I can have only one consumer group id, so if I don't have a task related to some topic named "foo", the data from "foo" will keep coming and the offset will be updated. If in the future I register a task to do something with "foo" the task will not process historic data from the topic.

Can I implement a custom kafka which extends FlinkKafkaConsumer to get those task from database then start a consume the topics the tasks are related with consumer group id provided by task itself?

The tasks need to refresh every N minutes to get alterations to task list provided by the external system.

I'm open to suggestions to another ideas too.

Comment: It sounds to me like you'd be better off managing your own source which wraps a KafkaConsumer, this way you can control both the consumer group ids and the topic offsets which you are reading from.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it sounds like all your jobs are totally independent of each other. You want each job to consume its data itself (with a kafka consumer group) so that three jobs on the same kafka topic also receive the data three times. You probably also want that if some job is slow, the others aren't blocked in processing.

My suggestion would thus be: Start a single flink session but deploy your jobs in it indepenently. You would need to build kind of a deployment component/script that receives tasks from your task source and starts or stops jobs.

Each job can be configured to have a dedicated kafka consumer group id and can be configured to commit to that group on checkpoint. On the next restart, you can either start from state (Where the job left off last, e.g. from a savepoint) or you don't provide a checkpoint/savepoint and tell it to start from the committed group id offsets.